# Return first order date and amount per customer

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to run a Python (pandas) script that returns the initial_order_DT as a column and initial_order_value as another column.

**Input:**

```
        Order ID     Customer ID   Value   Date
        00000001     0001          1500     10/01/2017
        00000002     0001          1300     11/15/2017
        00000003     0001          1200     12/12/2017
        00000004     0002          500      12/13/2017
        00000005     0003          1750     09/15/2017
        00000006     0003          1800     10/01/2017
        00000007     0003          1600     11/01/2017
        00000008     0003          1400     12/01/2017
```

**Output:**

```
        Order ID     Customer ID   Value   Date  First_Order_DT First_Value 
        00000001     0001          1500    //     10/01/2017    1500
        00000002     0001          1300    //     10/01/2017    1500
        00000003     0001          1200    //     10/01/2017    1500
        00000004     0002          500     //     12/13/2017    500
        00000005     0003          1750    //     09/15/2017    1750
        00000006     0003          1800    //     09/15/2017    1750
        00000007     0003          1600    //     09/15/2017    1750
        00000008     0003          1400     etc   09/15/2017    1750
```

Comment: Okay, we already know what you want, but we want to know what you have tried. SO is not a coding service, read the rules of [ask].

Comment: It's okay. I consider it a win when a pandas question has data and expected output.

Comment: @Coldspeed. Thanks a lot for this solution. It works like a charm. I wanted to vote for your answer but I couldn't do it since I'm new to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `groupby` + `transform` -

```
v = df.groupby('Customer ID')['Date', 'Value'].transform('first').add_prefix('First_')
v
   First_Date  First_Value
0  10/01/2017         1500
1  10/01/2017         1500
2  10/01/2017         1500
3  12/13/2017          500
4  09/15/2017         1750
5  09/15/2017         1750
6  09/15/2017         1750
7  09/15/2017         1750
```

Concatenate `v` with the original `df` -

```
df = pd.concat([df, v], 1)
df

   Order ID  Customer ID  Value        Date  First_Date  First_Value
0         1            1   1500  10/01/2017  10/01/2017         1500
1         2            1   1300  11/15/2017  10/01/2017         1500
2         3            1   1200  12/12/2017  10/01/2017         1500
3         4            2    500  12/13/2017  12/13/2017          500
4         5            3   1750  09/15/2017  09/15/2017         1750
5         6            3   1800  10/01/2017  09/15/2017         1750
6         7            3   1600  11/01/2017  09/15/2017         1750
7         8            3   1400  12/01/2017  09/15/2017         1750
```

Comment: @Coldspeed. Thanks a lot for this solution. It works like a charm. I wanted to vote for your answer but I couldn't do it since I'm new to Stackoverflow

Comment: @Coldspeed done! thanks again. I would be appreciative also if you give a vote for my question. I'm sure a lot of people could benefit from it also :)